# Pass in Arguments when Doing a Docker Run

Tags: docker

If I have the following Dockfile

```
FROM centos:8
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y python38-pip
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

With app being the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
print('Here is your param: ', sys.argv[0])
```

When I call docker run -it (myimg), how can I pass in a parameter so the output would be the param?

ex:

```
docker run -it (myparam) "testfoo"

would print 

Here is your param: testfoo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.argv[0]` refer to the `FileName` so you can not expect `testfoo` when you run `docker run -it my_image testfoo`

> The first item in the list, `sys.argv[0]`, is the **name of the Python script**. The rest of the list elements, `sys.argv[1] to sys.argv[n]`, are the **command line arguments** 2 through n

```
print('Here is your param: file Name', sys.argv[0],'args testfoo:',sys.argv[1])
```

So you can just replace the entrypoint to below then you are good to pass runtime argument `testfoo`

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3","app.py"]
```

Now pass argument `testfoo`

```
docker run -it --rm my_image testfoo
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything you provide after the image name in the `docker run` command line replaces the `CMD` from the Dockerfile, and then that gets appended to the `ENTRYPOINT` to form a complete command.

Since you put the script name in `CMD`, you need to repeat that in the `docker run` invocation:

```sh
docker run -it myimg app.py testfoo
```

(This split of `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` seems odd to me.  I'd make sure the script  starts with a line like `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and is executable, so you can directly run `./app.py`; make that be the `CMD` and remove the `ENTRYPOINT` entirely.)